# remove a row of a tablelayout at a click of a button in android studio

Tags: android, onclicklistener, tablelayout

I have a code like this to remove a view at the click of a button:

```
 onClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ((LinearLayout)v.getParent()).removeView(v);              
        }
 };
```

then I use this command to set the action at the click:

```
 button.setOnClickListener( onClick );
```

The problem is that I want to remove a row of a TableLayout at the click,
not the button. How can I do that?

Comment: find that tablelayout by id and set visibility to VISIBILITY.GONE

Comment: Can you please post your xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code,

```
onClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {            
            View row = (View) v.getParent();            
            ViewGroup container = ((ViewGroup)row.getParent());
            container.removeView(row);
            container.invalidate();         
        }
    };
```

Comment: If the button would actually be inside the TableRow this answer would indeed work. However, that has never been stated in the original question.

Comment: @DaniëlvandenBerg yes I forgot to explicitly say it. The button is inside the TableRow. Otherwise, what would the solution be?

Comment: @Helios83 See my answer 1 below ;)

Answer (score 0):

You're looking in the right direction, but not entirely there yet.
 ***`onClick(View v)`*** is a method that gets called when the button is clicked, and parameter ***`v`*** is the view that got clicked. In this case, the button. So, when saying ***`removeView(v);`***, you're saying *`"Remove the view that just got clicked"`*.

What you want to do instead is the following:

1. Find your TableRow view. (Give it an ID, and use findViewByID(R.id.yourID) to find it.)
2. Get the parent of that table row (You're already doing that for button by doing `((LinearLayout)v.getParent())`, so you can adapt that and use it again)
3. Call the `removeView(View v)` method of the parent, with as argument the TableRow view you found in step 1.

I'd recommend that you try to implement this yourself first. If you really can't figure it out, just leave a comment and I'll add a code example.

Comment: cool, thanks. I just want to add that if the view is created dynamically (as in my case), to get the id one gets it with view.getid(). To set it, one uses instead the command view.setid(something).

Comment: If you're creating it dynamically you could also just store the view in a list or map. That's faster than calling `findViewByID`.